# Tomar una foto y añadirla a imageView dinamico

Tags: android, cámara

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que añade dinámicamente un `array` de `imageview` y llamo a la cámara para hacer una foto y añadirla a ese `imageview` y me da `null pointer excption`.

Este es el método donde se crean diatónicamente los `imageviews`

```
    private void añadirAveria() {
     refer=edtRefer.getText().toString();
     descrip=edtDescrip.getText().toString();
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lip= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     lip.setMargins(0,50,0,0);

     LinearLayout.LayoutParams lap= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     lap.setMargins(25,0,25,0);

     layoutPhoto[contadorAverias]=new LinearLayout(this);
     layoutPhoto[contadorAverias].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
     camara[contadorAverias]=new ImageView(this);
     camara[contadorAverias].setLayoutParams(lap);
     camara[contadorAverias].setImageResource(R.drawable.photocamara64);
     camara[contadorAverias].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
             uriFoto = Uri.fromFile(
                     new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                             +"Inadeso_" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) + ".jpg"));
             Log.d("uriFoto: ", uriFoto.toString() );
             intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriFoto);
             startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
         }
     });

     galeria[contadorAverias]=new ImageView(this);
     galeria[contadorAverias].setLayoutParams(lap);
     galeria[contadorAverias].setImageResource(R.drawable.picturegallery);
     eliminarFoto[contadorAverias]=new ImageView(this);
     eliminarFoto[contadorAverias].setLayoutParams(lap);
     eliminarFoto[contadorAverias].setImageResource(R.drawable.deletepicture);
     fotografia[contadorAverias]=new ImageView(this);
     fotografia[contadorAverias].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
     fotografia[contadorAverias].setId(contadorAverias);

     btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias]=new ImageButton(this);
     btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias].setImageResource(R.drawable.eliminar);
     btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     final Spinner spinnerTrabajos=new Spinner(this);
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ArrayTiposTrabajos);
     spinnerTrabajos.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
     refi[contadorAverias]=new TextView(this);
     refi[contadorAverias].setText("Referencia");
     desc[contadorAverias]=new TextView(this);
     desc[contadorAverias].setText("Descripcion");
     textHor[contadorAverias]=new TextView(this);
     textHor[contadorAverias].setText("Horas Trabajadas:");
     texTip[contadorAverias]=new TextView(this);
     texTip[contadorAverias].setText("Tipo de trabajo: ");
     ref[contadorAverias]=new EditText(this);
     incis2[contadorAverias] = new EditText(this);
     incis2[contadorAverias].setText (descrip);
     ref[contadorAverias].setText(refer);
     ref[contadorAverias].setEnabled(false);
     tipoTrab2[contadorAverias]=new Spinner(this);
     tipoTrab2[contadorAverias].setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
     horasTrabAve[contadorAverias] = new EditText(this);
     horasTrabAve[contadorAverias].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
     btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             new AlertDialog.Builder(NuevoParte_1.this)
                     .setTitle( "Borrar" )
                     .setMessage( "Desea borrar este registro?" )
                     .setPositiveButton( "Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             layoutAverias.removeView(refi[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(ref[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(desc[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(incis2[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(textHor[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(horasTrabAve[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(texTip[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(tipoTrab2[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias-1]);
                             layoutAverias.removeView(layoutPhoto[contadorAverias-1]);
                             contadorAverias=contadorAverias-1;
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton( "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Negative" );
                         }
                     } )
                     .show();
         }
     });
     refi[contadorAverias].setLayoutParams(lip);
     layoutAverias.addView(refi[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(ref[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(desc[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(incis2[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(textHor[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(horasTrabAve[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(texTip[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(tipoTrab2[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(btnEliminarAve[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(layoutPhoto[contadorAverias]);
     layoutAverias.addView(fotografia[contadorAverias]);
     //Layout de Foto por averia

     layoutPhoto[contadorAverias].addView(camara[contadorAverias]);
     layoutPhoto[contadorAverias].addView(galeria[contadorAverias]);
     layoutPhoto[contadorAverias].addView(eliminarFoto[contadorAverias]);
    // layoutPhoto[contadorAverias].addView(fotografia[contadorAverias]);

     edtRefer.setText("");
     edtDescrip.setText("");
     contadorAverias=contadorAverias+1;

}
```

Aquí muestro el `activityforresult`

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int  resultCode,Intent mat){
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultCode, mat);
    switch (requestcode){
        case 0:
            if (RESULT_OK==resultCode){

                String materialCreado=mat.getStringExtra("material");
                String canti=mat.getStringExtra("cantidad");

                btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial]=new ImageButton(this);
                btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial].setImageResource(R.drawable.eliminar2);
                btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                mater[contadorMaterial]=new TextView(this);
                mater[contadorMaterial].setText(materialCreado);
                final TextView cant=new TextView(this);
                cant.setText("Cantidad:");
                cantidad[contadorMaterial]=new EditText(this);
                cantidad[contadorMaterial].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(NuevoParte_1.this)
                                .setTitle( "Borrar" )
                                .setMessage( "Desea borrar este registro?" )
                                .setPositiveButton( "Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        layoutMateriales.removeView(mater[contadorMaterial-1]);
                                        layoutMateriales.removeView(cantidad[contadorMaterial-1]);
                                        layoutMateriales.removeView(btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial-1]);
                                        layoutMateriales.removeView(cant);
                                        contadorMaterial=contadorMaterial-1;
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton( "No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Negative" );
                                    }
                                } )
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                cantidad[contadorMaterial].setText(canti);
                datocant= cantidad[contadorMaterial].getText().toString();
                dato2cant=datocant;
                cantidadString.add(dato2cant);
                layoutMateriales.addView(mater[contadorMaterial]);
                layoutMateriales.addView(cant);
                layoutMateriales.addView(cantidad[contadorMaterial]);
                layoutMateriales.addView(btnEliminarMat[contadorMaterial]);
                contadorMaterial=contadorMaterial+1;

            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(RESULT_OK==resultCode && uriFoto!=null){
                textFoto = uriFoto.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "De camara: " + textoFoto);

                //Lugares.actualizaLugar((int) id, lugar);

                ponerFoto(fotografia[contadorAverias], textFoto);

    }

            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }



}
```

Y este es un método para añadir la imagen al `imageview`

```
    protected void ponerFoto(ImageView imageView, String uri) {
    if ((uri == null) || (uri.equals(""))) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    } else {
        //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        // El codigo a continuacion escala la imagen para evitar fallo de memoria al guardarla
        Bitmap d = null;
        try{
            d= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(uri));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int nh = (int) (d.getHeight() * (254.0 / d.getWidth()));

        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 254, nh, true);
        //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Toast.makeText(NuevoParte_1.this,"llego aki",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

El error que me arroja:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.pronegotec.inadeso, PID: 4036
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.pronegotec.inadeso/com.pronegotec.inadeso.NuevoParte_1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.pronegotec.inadeso.NuevoParte_1.ponerFoto(NuevoParte_1.java:513)
>                         at com.pronegotec.inadeso.NuevoParte_1.onActivityResult(NuevoParte_1.java:482)
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

Comment: Podrías indicar las lineas 482 y 513 de la clase NuevoParte_1 ?